# Sencha Ext JS in a Chrome App?

Tags: extjs, google-chrome-app

I'm using the latest version of Sencha Ext JS, version [4.2.2](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/). I would like to build a Chrome App **without using a sandbox frame** as documented in [Build Apps with Sencha Ext JS](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sencha_framework). Is there a patch/fork available to make Ext JS work in this more secure environment?

Just doing the Hello World with ext-dev.js from ext-4.2.2-commercial.zip, I get these errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't know the answer, but it seems like a good question to me. Somebody downrated it to -1, so I am kicking it up by 1.

Comment: Thanks, I spent several hours trying to make this work yesterday after work. I'll edit the question and add more details about the errors I was getting to show that I did research the question and try things out.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to get to some conclusion on this please?

Comment: My conclusion was that if you are going to use ExtJS, then you do indeed want to put it in a sandbox frame.

Answer (score 0):

The framework has evolved significantly during the last ten years.  There are numerous new changes between the 4.x and 7.x versions, as you can see. The newest version is Ext JS 7.7. Check here: https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/evaluate/.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_with_npm.html